# Sphinx-js warnings for function parameter types

Tags: javascript, python-sphinx

I am attempting to add some documentation of JavaScript code using the [sphinx-js](https://github.com/mozilla/sphinx-js) plugin for Sphinx. When running `make html`, I am seeing warnings regarding the type specifications for function parameters.

The test JavaScript function I am using is:

```
/**
 * This is a description.
 * @param {String} first This is the first parameter.
 * @param {Number} second This is the second parameter.
 */
function testFunction(first, second) {}
```

And in my `.rst` file:

```
.. js:autofunction:: testFunction
```

This generates the following warnings:

```
util.js:testFunction(6):24: WARNING: js:func reference target not found: String
util.js:testFunction(6):24: WARNING: js:func reference target not found: Number
```

I should note that the documentation generates just fine. The documentation block for `testFunction` is included, along with the parameters list and their types. But I assume the warnings are there for a reason?

According to the plugin's [usage documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/sphinx-js#use), "autodoc"-style documentation of function parameters - with or without types - is fully supported. And the generated documentation appears to be complete. Is there actually an issue here? Can I resolve these warnings?

I am using:

```
sphinx 1.8.3
sphinx-js 2.7.1
jsdoc 3.5.5
```